# Laravel - Eloquent relation - many-to-many - get intermediate table columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-8

I have a question about Laravel Eloquent Relations.

I have the following table situation:

Table `guests`:

- id
- name
- ...

Table `landing_pages`:

- id
- name
- ...

A guest can have several landing pages. And a landing page will have multiple guests.
So I thought, I can use a `many-to-many` relationship there and I created a new table

Table `guests_landing_pages`:

- id
- guest_id
- landing_page_id
- ...

I would be able to use this the following way:
In `guest` Model I can do this, to create the `many-to-many` relationship:

```
public function landing_pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\LandingPage\LandingPage::class, 'guests_landing_pages','landing_page_id','guest_id');
}
```

... and the other way round in `landing_page` model.
But actually the table `guests_landing_pages` contains more data than just the `guest_id` and `landing_page_id` relation.
There are several other fields in it:

Table `guests_landing_pages`:

- id
- guest_id
- landing_page_id
- identifier_token
- max_persons
- answer
- ...

My question is now, how can I realize this best. If I would use the `many-to-many` relation as described above, I will not be able to access the fields in the intermediate table, won't I?
Or will the best solution to this to create a `GuestLandingPages` model with all the fields and create `hasMany` relations to/in both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel Eloquent has features for retrieving intermediate columns.

```
public function landing_pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\LandingPage\LandingPage::class, 'guests_landing_pages','landing_page_id','guest_id')
                ->withPivot('max_persons', 'answers');
}
```